# Can you check docker's cache without building the image?

Tags: docker

Does docker have a command to check *whether* there would be a cache hit, but without running the full build? i.e., the step that the `docker build` command runs internally to check for file changes?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by cache? Are you referring to layers or the RUN cache?

Comment: The layers that get cached when you run `docker build ...`.  If context helps, the use case would be calling from a script and flagging which images are 'stale' and should be rebuilt, but without simple calling `build` on them continually.

Comment: To be honest, I don’t understand this use case: In my opinion, Docker already does this in the most efficient way: On demand, it checks which layers are stale and then rebuilds them. Can you please elaborate why you want to circumvent Docker? What would be the benefit, or, what shortcoming of Docker would this address?

Comment: I don't want to circumvent docker, I'm asking whether docker has this functionality. I have n containers running on my machine, one of which I'm debugging. If I change code in the service I'm debugging, it is clear to me that I should rebuild this service. However, it may not occur to me that the code impacts other currently running containers. I want to be able to highlight which currently running images should be rebuilt, but without having to continually restart and rebuild all containers. Does this make more sense?